# Two Android libraries duplicate the same jar - Ant build error

Tags: android, ant

I have a project that uses two independent Android libraries. Each of them contains Android support package, so that ant build fails on 'dex' step:

```
   [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)
   [dx] 1 error; aborting
```

What should I do?

I'm going to move one of these jar files out of the libs folder in **-post-compile** target. And then move it back after dex step is finished.
What are your recommendations?

**UPDATE:**
I've tried to move the support package out of one the libraries in **-post-compile** target but it still fails because of another reason. This jar is already included to the path that is processed by dex task. And dex task cannot open the removed jar.

Comment: you could have one library depend on the other, and add the support package only there

Comment: I also thought about it, but want to use them independently

Comment: Looks like it will be fixed in r17 of Android tools.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21169

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix is already implemented in ADT-r17  preview builds.

More details here:
http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

Comment: Think, I'll make these libraries dependent and place support package in one place, and will be waiting for the upcoming release :)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid having the same library in both. Can't you exclude one support package specifically using wildcards from one of the libraries at compile time of your project? By filtering it out with proguard, for instance:

```
-libraryjars  ${android.libraryjars}(!org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.class,!org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException.class,!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,!META-INF/NOTICE.txt,!META-INF/LICENSE.txt)
```